# Perfect square of the form 1444...

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

> Let A1 = 14, and let An be the number of the form 1444... with n fours following the 1. Find all n such that An is a perfect square.

It is obvious that A2 = 144 is a perfect square and possibly the only one, yet I haven't found a way to prove that.

Possibly the biggest hint is that if $$ An = (13*10^n - 4) / 9\\$$
and if $$ An = k^2 $$

then $$ k = 13i + 1 \\ or \\ k = 13i + 12 $$
for some value of i.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342457/does-the-sequnce-144-1-444-14-444-144-444-contain-any-squares-besides-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, let $A_{n} = k^2$. You've checked for $n = 1$ and, for $n = 2$, you have $144 = 12^2$. Also, note with $n = 3$ that you have a solution of $1444 = 38^2$. Thus, next consider only cases where $n \ge 4$.

You have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
k^2 & = \frac{13(10^{n}) - 4}{9} \\
9k^2 & = 13(5^{n})(2^{n}) - 4 \\
(3k)^2 & = 4((13)(5^{n})(2^{n-2}) - 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This means $k$ is even, let's say $k = 2j$. You can substitute this into \eqref{eq1A} and divide both sides by $4$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(3j)^2 & = (13)(5^{n})(2^{n-2}) - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

For $n \ge 4$, you have $4$ divides $2^{n-2}$. This means that $(3j)^2$ has a remainder of $-1$, which is equivalent to $3$, when divided by $4$. However, all perfect squares have a remainder of only $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$. This shows there are no solutions for $n \ge 4$, with the only solutions being for $n = 2$ and $n = 3$.

Regarding your hint that $k = 13i + 1$ or $k = 13i + 12$, I don't know of any way to use it to determine the set of valid values of $n$.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Excelent response! I forgot that useful property of squares.I also thought that by the nature of k and remainder would be useful for getting to the answer, yet as you saw I believed 13 would be the one to hint the answer.